# How to set a master/admin access in a Laravel framework php application?

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently been handed over a web application built with the Laravel framework.  I come from the PHP programming world and with little exposure to Frameworks (briefly worked with a Zend app).

I need to setup a common master password, that would allow the user to access all the users accounts.  I am not sure how the laravel AuthenticateUsers.php works and need some help.

In my LoginController.php, I have the following code

```
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
 {
     if ($this->username() === 'email') return $this->attemptLoginAtAuthenticatesUsers($request);
     if ( ! $this->attemptLoginAtAuthenticatesUsers($request)) {
         return $this->attempLoginUsingUsernameAsAnEmail($request);
     }
     return false;
}
    protected function attempLoginUsingUsernameAsAnEmail(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        ['email' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')],
        $request->has('remember'));
}
```

The requirement is that the master/admin user should be able to access any user's account by using a common password. I do need to validate that it is a valid username.

So I updated the code in function attempLoginUsingUsernameAsAnEmail() as below to log into any users account using master/admin password 'Adm123!'. Also, tried using loginUsingId (line commented in code below), but neither of them worked.

```
protected function attempLoginUsingUsernameAsAnEmail(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('password') == "Adm123!") {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            ['email' => $request->input('username')]);

    // $this->guard()->loginUsingId($request->input('username'));
    }
    else {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            ['email' => $request->input('username'), 'password' => $request->input('password')],
            $request->has('remember'));
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?  And, is there a better approach to what I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single shared password means no auditing of what the admin does. You're better off using a "masquerade" or "impersonate" approach, where a privileged user can temporarily act as another user. There's a nice plugin for this, incidentally. https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz.  Seems like the 'impersonate' approach is the way to go.  Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Is [impersonation](https://github.com/404labfr/laravel-impersonate) not a better, more secure method of achieving this?

Comment: You probably want to rephrase this into a longer answer so people aren't inclined to flag it as "Should be a Comment" or "Link Only Answer".